# Laravel Empty Password hashing

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

When I trying to update user data and let The Password Field empty it hashed again that means the password will change and you can't log in again
so is there any way to fix this problem ??

Code

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'first_name'=> 'required|string',
        'last_name' =>  'required|string',
        'email'     =>  'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::id(),
        'password'  =>  'sometimes|nullable|string|min:8,'.Auth::id(),
        'avatar'    =>  'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png,svg|max:2048,'.Auth::id(),
        'gender'    =>  'required',
        'country_id'=>  'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->gender = $request->gender;
    $user->country_id = $request->country_id;
    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename ) );
        $user->avatar = $filename;
    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: show us some code. Controller method that updates, data you are sending ...

Comment: @N69S I update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if there is a `passoword` in the request object first.

```php
if($request->password){
 $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
}
```

After editing it, it will be like this:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'first_name'=> 'required|string',
    'last_name' =>  'required|string',
    'email'     =>  'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::id(),
    'password'  =>  'sometimes|nullable|string|min:8,'.Auth::id(),
    'avatar'    =>  'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png,svg|max:2048,'.Auth::id(),
    'gender'    =>  'required',
    'country_id'=>  'required',
]);

$user = User::find(Auth::id());

$user->first_name = $request->first_name;
$user->last_name = $request->last_name;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->gender = $request->gender;
$user->country_id = $request->country_id;

if($request->password){
    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
}

if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename ) );
    $user->avatar = $filename;
}

$user->save();

return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: take a look at this image http://prntscr.com/rc1aoz from https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/php_pitfalls/ doing `if(!empty($var))` is equivalent to `if ($var)`

Comment: there is no need to use `!empty` because `request->password` is defined even if it returns `null`

Comment: @N69S why downvote? is there a problem with my answer?

Comment: @Joseph Thanks this fixes my problem 

Now the password field no longer hashed if I let it empty

Comment: You posted your answer without reading the answers already present.

Comment: @N69S i answer from 14min and you from 13min

Comment: @N69S i think that it is you i am sorry for miss understood

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test on the password if it is present.

```php
$this->validate($request, [
        'first_name'=> 'required|string',
        'last_name' =>  'required|string',
        'email'     =>  'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::id(),
        'password'  =>  'sometimes|nullable|string|min:8,'.Auth::id(),
        'avatar'    =>  'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png,svg|max:2048,'.Auth::id(),
        'gender'    =>  'required',
        'country_id'=>  'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->gender = $request->gender;
    $user->country_id = $request->country_id;
    if ($request->password) {
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    }
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename ) );
        $user->avatar = $filename;
    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you may change your validation rule to check if `password` is not empty when present:

```php
'password'  =>  'sometimes|required|string|min:8',
```

Then `bcrypt` if it's not empty and present on the request vie `$request->filled()` method:

```php
if ($request->filled('password'))
{
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
}
```